# How to start all the ec2 instances using python by configuring boto3 libraries in windows?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3, botocore

I have installed python 3.6.4 version on my windows 8.1 64-bit machine.
what all steps required to install and configure **boto3 and boto** libraries.
I was trying to fetch all the **AWS EC2 instances** of particular region and stoping them, but not able to execute the task.

Do anybody have solution to accomplished the requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Credentials to environment variables:
[Doc to configure credentials](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html)

Set region for your boto3 client:
[Tutorial to Set region](https://russell.ballestrini.net/setting-region-programmatically-in-boto3/)

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-west-2') #Add your region

print('Loading function')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    responses = client.start_instances(
    InstanceIds=[
        'YOUR INSTANCE IDs'
    ],

    DryRun=True # Make it False to test
)
```

Comment: Hey Parashar,
thank you so much for the solution.
I completed my task just in a different way, you solution is really appreciated.
kindly look at my way out, hope it might help somebody.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Basic import boto3 libraries
import boto3
import sys

#provided Access Credentialsaccess_key
access_key = ""
secret_key = ""

count=0
#Establish a connection to EC2 resource using credentials and region_name
conn = boto3.resource('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name='us-west-1')
print("Argument length: ",len(sys.argv))

if len(sys.argv)>2:
    Keyname = sys.argv[1]
    value = sys.argv[2]
    instances = conn.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped'],'Name': 'tag:'+Keyname,'Values': [value]}])
    print("Arguments passed\nKey: "+Keyname+"\nValue: "+value)
else:
    instances = conn.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}])

for instance in instances:
    #instance.start(instance.id)
    count+=1
    print(instance.id,",",instance.state["Name"])

print("Total number of EC2 instances are stopped on cloud: ",count)
```

Above code can be executed with 2 parameters, 1st is the Tag Key of all the instances and 2nd is the Tag Value.
it will fetch all the running instaces which are taged with the given value and start them one by one.

Comment: Up-voted, as Your answer solves the purpose. While the answer, I gave is a generic way to manage ec2 with api. Also, for your solution, 1 suggestion is: Since instances are created usually without adding tags, try to add the relevant tag first (with same code and not manually) and then stop instances. Flow will be.. Add tag, if not already added to the instance > Get all the instance IDs with that tag now > stop them. However, it won't help with Elastic Beanstalk instances. Also, You can Check Tags: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#tag

Comment: Hey Parashar,
Your suggestion is truly appreciated. I would like to let you know that, we already have all the instances configured with the tag and their values. But, as you said, the flow should be the way you are saying.
thanks you so much for the clarification of this problem statement.